# Search command is not working as intended | discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I'm new to economy commands and I'm still figuring out how to use `bot.wait_for` So I'm sorry if this is an easy fix. So I'm making a search command however it isn't working. Even after using code blocks to type where I wanna search the bot still doesnt work. [Image's](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/761584549153996802/772703987774128138/unknown.png)

Here's the code

```
  @commands.command()
  async def search(self, ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    place = [f'`couch`', f"`park`", f"`road`"]
    place1 = [f"`dog`", f"`tree`", "`car`"]
    place2 = [f"`discord`", f"`grass`", f"`pocket`"]

    await ctx.send(f"Where do you wanna search? Pick from the list below.\n {random.choice(place)},{random.choice(place1)}, {random.choice(place2)}")
    
    answer = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)

    if answer.content.lower() == place or answer.content == place1 or answer.content == place2:
      earnings = random.randrange(301)
      await update_bank(ctx.author, earnings, "wallet")
      await ctx.send(f"You just found {earnings} coins. Cool")
      return
    else:
      await ctx.send("Thats not a part of the list tho?")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement is the problem. Youre checking wether the word typed in equals to one of the lists. You should rather do a list of the available words and then check if the given word is in that list:

```
@client.command()
async def search(ctx):

    place1 = ["couch", "park", "road"]
    place2 = ["dog", "tree", "car"]
    place3 = ["discord", "grass", "pocket"]

    places = [random.choice(place1), random.choice(place2), random.choice(place3)]
    placesToSearch = ', '.join([f"`{x.title()}`" for x in places])

    await ctx.send(f"Where do you wanna search? Pick from the list below.\n {placesToSearch}")
    response = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)

    if response.content.lower() in places:
        earnings = random.randrange(301)
        await ctx.send(f"You just found {earnings} coins. Cool")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Thats not a part of the list tho?")
```